# Android Apk protecting using proguard

Tags: android, azure, proguard

I have generated an apk file which has proguard but When I am trying to connect with azure it is giving some exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod` to my proguard 
Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an exception of the classes in your jar files. For instance I was using roboguice so I added this:

```
# Keep the classes in the external jars
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; } 
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; } 
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; } 
-keep class roboguice.** { *; }
```

I was also using XStream so in my proguard-project.txt i did added the following:

```
#Keep the classes for XStream jar
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.SubjectConverter { *; }
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.ThrowableConverter { *; }
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.StackTraceElementConverter { *; }
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.CurrencyConverter { *; }
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.RegexPatternConverter { *; }
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.CharsetConverter { *; }
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.** { *; }
```

So what I would try is to add the classes that the jar files provide you

Comment: not working .. i have added like this -keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTable { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterResponse { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.TableOperationCallback { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.TableQueryCallback { *; }
-keep class com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.** { *; }

Comment: When i am trying to connect with table I am getting "class representing the mobileservicetable must have a single id property defined" exception

Comment: Can you post more information?? looks like you are missing a model or something :(